# Phpunit: replace class with mock

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to replace some class instantiation with the mock one so that when I call `new SomeClass()` the mock one is created with specified mocked behavior?

Comment: Did you read this https://phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly **not recommended** but possible, take a look at links bellow

https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers

https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz

It's better to use Dependency Injection (simply, it means injecting instances as arguments to function instead of creating them inside the function). As a result you will be able easily to mock that argument while testing.
You can google about other pros of DI, but here a few links for you:
[answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection), [DI and phpunit](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-4-mock-objects-stub-methods-dependency-injection/)

Comment: Thank you, think the best way is to refactor code to use DI